# Get Last 2 Decimal Places with No Rounding

Tags: c#, rounding, decimal

In C#, I'm trying to get the last two decimal places of a double with NO rounding.  I've tried everything from `Math.Floor` to `Math.Truncate` and nothing is working.

Samples of the results I'd like:

```
1,424.2488298 -> 1,424.24
53.5821 -> 53.58
10,209.2991 -> 10,209.29
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're doing work in *decimal* then why are you using *double* when you could be using *decimal*?

Comment: You can go to this post and find what it fits for you http://how-to-code-net.blogspot.ro/2012/09/how-to-format-number-to-x-decimal.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, mathematically it's simple:

```
var f = 1.1234;
f = Math.Truncate(f * 100) / 100;  // f == 1.12
```

Move the decimal two places to the right, cast to an int to truncate, shift it back to the left two places.  There may be ways in the framework to do it too, but I can't look right now.  You could generalize it:

```
double Truncate(double value, int places)
{
    // not sure if you care to handle negative numbers...       
    var f = Math.Pow( 10, places );
    return Math.Truncate( value * f ) / f;
}
```

Comment: Not so simple.  Doubles hold a larger range than ints.

Comment: @joe: Ahh good point, use Math.Truncate instead, no cast required

Comment: @EdS. I tried this on the value 136.2025 using your first method and it trimmed it to 136.2 and dropped the 0.  Is there a way to keep the 0 in it?

Comment: @mint: Well, now you're talking about display, not the number itself.  There is no difference between `136.2`, `136.20`, and `136.2000000`.  If you want to print with a certain number of places displayed then look into string formatting in calls to `String.Format`.

Comment: @mint: Make sure to also note what Eric Lippert said in his post.  You may be better off using the `decimal` type, and the multiplication will fail if it would result in a number larger than the max value for a `double`.

Answer (score 15):

My advice: **stop using `double` in the first place**. If you need decimal rounding then odds are good you should be using `decimal`. What is your application?

If you do have a double, you can do it like this:

```
double r = whatever;
decimal d = (decimal)r;
decimal truncated = decimal.Truncate(d * 100m) / 100m;
```

Note that this technique will fail if the absolute value of the double is larger than 792281625142643375935439504, because the multiplication by 100 will fail. If you need to handle values that large then you'll need to use special techniques. (Of course, by the time a double is that large, you are well beyond its ability to represent values with two digits after the decimal place anyway.)

Answer (score 6):

```
 double d = Math.Truncate(d * 100) / 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

A general solution:

```
    public static double SignificantTruncate(double num, int significantDigits)
    {
        double y = Math.Pow(10, significantDigits);
        return Math.Truncate(num * y) / y;
    }
```

Then

```
    double x = 5.3456;
    x = SignificantTruncate(x,2);
```

Will produce the desired result `x=5.34`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Math.Round(NumberToRound - (double)0.005,2)
```

i.e

```
Math.Round(53.5821 - (double)0.005,2) // 53.58
Math.Round(53.5899 - (double)0.005,2) // 53.58
Math.Round(53.5800 - (double)0.005,2) // 53.58
```

Answer (score 0):

Octane i generalized your answer, it does not suffer from exceeding max values.. works like a charm :)

```
int dec = 4; 
return Math.Round(val - (decimal)(5 / Math.Pow(10,dec+1)), dec)
```