# Avoid round off decimals in Datagridview control

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, c#-3.0

In the Datagridview I have a column **"C"** which is product of Column **"A"** and **"B"**.
Example 
Column A Value - 8.14
Column B Value - 0.2
 Now the column C value is **12.296** and after decimal I want to show first two  numbers like
**12.29** without rounding to **12.30**.

Below is the code  i used to achieve the above result.

```
public class CustomFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;
        else
            return null;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        // Check whether this is an appropriate callback             
        if (!this.Equals(formatProvider))
            return null;

        if (arg == null) return null;

        string numericString = arg.ToString();

        decimal result = 0;

        if (Decimal.TryParse(numericString, out result))
        {
            return ((Math.Truncate(result * 100)) / 100).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

private void gvItemDetails_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == gvItemDetails.Columns["Vat Amount"].Index)
        {
            gvItemDetails[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = String.Format(new CustomFormatter(), "{0}", e.Value);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

When i put a break point on cellformatting code..i can see the code is repeated continously but not returning any stackoverflow exception. When i remove the breakpoint its working.

Can you please advice what might be the problem or suggest any other alternative to prevent it from rounding an show 12.29 not 12.30.

Thanks,
Prathap.

Comment: What do you want to fix exactly?

Comment: Forget about the error...I just want to show 12.29 and not 12.30.How can i achieve this in datagridview.

Comment: Duplicate of [get-last-2-decimal-places-with-no-rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931795/get-last-2-decimal-places-with-no-rounding)

Comment: In case of datagridview the same implementation will not work i guess.I am looking for the DefaultCellStyle.Format instead of complex solutions like implementing customformatter and cellformatting

Answer (score 1):

First, i tried to use the same method which you used. It works perfectly fine for me and produces desired "12.29".

```
string numericString = "12.2963";
string truncatedString = string.Empty;
decimal result = 0;

if (Decimal.TryParse(numericString, out result))
{
     truncatedString = ((Math.Truncate(result * 100)) / 100).ToString();
}
```

In case, above method doesn't work for you, another simple alternative would be to use string.substring (this will be useful only when intermediate decimal value is not required for you).

```
string numericString = "12.2963";
string truncatedString = string.Empty;value
int endIndex = numericString.IndexOf('.');
truncatedString = numericString.Substring(0, endIndex + 3);
```

Update:

Though i haven't tested it, you should be able to define format provider this way :

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["XYZ"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = new CustomFormatter();
```

and for format (here format string will have pre-defined meaning) :

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["XYZ"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
```

Update 2:
Unfortunately, even if you are using FormatProvider, you still need to handle cellformatting event; [Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551575/using-a-custom-formatter-in-a-datagridview/).

Good news is that you don't need to use FormatProvider for this. Try following format, it should work for you:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["XYZ"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.##";
```

Comment: Thanks for the sol.The solution which i used works fine for me too..but i can notice the cellformatting event is repeated n times.This may be dude to some other reason.Is there any simple way of setting the DefaultCellStyle.format for the Column instead of all this code.

Comment: Used the below line for my solution gvItemDetails.Columns["C"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = new CustomFormatter(); where the customformatter is the one i defined in my question.It not working its showing 12.296000 rather than 12.29

Comment: Did you put breakpoint in your CustomFormatter class and checked what string it is returning?

Comment: This is the code I am using .
gvItemDetails.DataSource=dtItems;
gvItemDetails.Columns["VAT Amount"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = new CustomFormatter(); 
Its not entering the CustomFormatter code.Am i missing something

Comment: Thanks mate for the different solutions.But its rounding off to the nearest number 12.3 when i use "0.##"

Comment: Thanks mate ... i don't the know the reason why the formatting event is occurring recursively so enabled the event after binding the datasource and disabled the same.Its working fine now.